# Notation for length of arbitrarily long sequences in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose I have the set of arbitrarily long sequences of dice rolls:

\begin{equation}
\Omega = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty [6]^n = \{ (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(1,1),(1,2),\ldots \}
\end{equation}

Given some sequence $\omega \in \Omega$, what's the notation to get the length of the sequence? Is it $|\omega|$?

Comment: I have seen that notation before; regardless, I would just take one sentence to define it before you use it to reinforce your meaning

Comment: I hope it is helpful to point out that $[6]^+$ is a common notation for the set of nonempty finite sequences with elements in the set $[6]$.  (See [Kleene plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Kleene_plus) for example.)

Comment: @MYUSERNAMEISALIE I thought that only worked for sets of strings.

Comment: Strings are exactly finite sequences.

Comment: Related: [How to denote the size of a list?](//math.stackexchange.com/q/1169890)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen each of the following notations used to represent the length of a finite sequence $\sigma$:

- $\vert\sigma\vert$
- $length(\sigma)$
- $lh(\sigma)$

Personally, I think all three are perfectly fine, although it's worth spending a sentence saying what your notation means.

Note that "$\vert\sigma\vert$" is actually perfectly correct for finite sequences: a sequence is a set of ordered pairs, so it's length is indeed its cardinality. That said, once we look at *infinite* sequences this breaks down - a sequence of ordertype $\mathbb{N}$ and a sequence of ordertype $\mathbb{N}+1$ have the same cardinality. Since I often deal with infinite sequences, I tend to prefer $length$ or $lh$.